# Magento: Adding current currency code infront of prices

Tags: magento

I am wanting to show my prices in Magento with the current code in front of the price:

AUD $5.50

I can't seem to find a setting for this and I'm having trouble trying to find some code or a plugin to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This should work by default, or at least it should show you some currency code before your price. To change the currency go to System->Configuration->General->Currency Setup and look for the Default Display Currency dropdown box. Whatever you change the value to there will be the default currency displayed. Unless its overridden by user preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try free module [Currency Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/niro/extension/5823/et_currencymanager)

There is available currency symbol replace for every currency. Change "$" to "AUD $".

Answer (score 1):

In app/design/frontend/YourInterface/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/price.phtml, find proper place(you should have many try :) )like this snippet code:

```
<span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price+$_weeeTaxAmount,true,false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
```

change

```
<?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price+$_weeeTaxAmount,true,false) ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo 'AUD '.$_coreHelper->currency($_price+$_weeeTaxAmount,true,false) ?>
```

This will add 'AUD ' to all of the prices.